# C++ GUI Moving point in Chart

Tags: c++, winforms, user-interface

My code is written in Visual Studio and I am going to create a GUI.

In this GUI is a chart. My code should draw and show a point in the chart, wait and then delete this point afterwards. It should do this again and again.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3000; i++)
    {
        this->chart1->Series["A"]->Points->AddXY(x_m1[i], y_m1[i]);
        this->chart1->Series["B"]->Points->AddXY(x_m2[i], y_m2[i]);
        this->chart1->Series["C"]->Points->AddXY(x_r[i - 1], y_r[i - 1]);

        Sleep(1);

        chart1->Series[3]->Points->Clear();
        chart1->Series[4]->Points->Clear();
        chart1->Series[5]->Points->Clear();
    }
```

The problem is, the program waits till all 3000 loops are done, then it draws the points and instantly deletes the points...

How could I solve the problem, so that I can see a moving point in this chart?

Comment: My first thought: the Sleep(1) just is not enough. Increase it to Sleep(150). What framework are you using for drawing the GUI?

Comment: I have already tried this but if i increase the Sleep(1) to Sleep(150) the programm sleeps but it does not show any points.

Comment: That means the program calculates all the points then sleeps for a long time and deleted all points so that you can see no points...

Comment: What framework are you using for drawing the GUI? Please edit your question. Sometimes, you need to trigger some updateGui method after changing its contents. I think that you need to tell the GUI to update its view after adding content (this sould be done right before the sleep)

Comment: I am using WindowsForm as my framework. That is a good point. Do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: I am unexperienced in WindowsForms and can not directly help you. Maybe you should simply hit something like "how to update windows forms gui chart" or something similar. This link may help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/make_it_better/2017/05/15/updating-windows-form-ui-elements-from-another-thread/

Comment: Thank you Maurice for tipp i will try it